# Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop icon is not running my BASH script

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, icons

I have a simple script runme.sh which works when i run from terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
chromium-browser "https://askubuntu.com/"
```

But i need to make it now runnable for normal Users. So i place a desktop icon Which is as following: /home/user1/Desktop/not_it_users.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Server
Comment=Share this
Exec=/var/tmp/runme.sh
Icon=computer
Terminal=true
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;
```

Now when i execute the not_it_users.desktop icon from desktop using mouse, it shows a terminal for less then 1 second and nothing happens? Expecting it should show me the chromium-browser, when i use runme.sh only then it works but not working with Desktop icon.

Comment: did you execute the `runme.sh` file?

Comment: YES - see Exec=/var/tmp/runme.sh

Comment: No I mean you need to run `chmod +x /var/tmp/runme.sh`

Comment: That is done since i made runme.sh and also if i manually execute runme.sh it works

Comment: could you please test with replacing `Exec=sh /var/tmp/runme.sh` in .desktop file?

Comment: Same problem with or without sh.

Comment: also with `Exec=bash /var/tmp/runme.sh`?

Comment: Same with or without bash/sh.

Comment: Is this a BUG in Ubuntu 14.04? When will this bug be resolved?

Comment: I don't know, in my system woks well but I don't know why not run for you. sorry

Comment: Change it from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `.desktop` file which inherits most of the Chromium launcher settings:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Server
Comment=Share this
Exec=/var/tmp/runme.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;
TargetEnvironment=Unity
Icon=chromium-browser
StartupWMClass=Chromium-browser
StartupNotify=true
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser
```

Or even better, without the call to your `runme.sh`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Server
Comment=Share this
Exec=chromium-browser "https://askubuntu.com/"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Network;RemoteAccess;
TargetEnvironment=Unity
Icon=chromium-browser
StartupWMClass=Chromium-browser
StartupNotify=true
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser
```

**Note**: Just ensure that `/home/user1/Desktop/not_it_users.desktop` permissions include the `+x` bit.

Comment: Thank you its working since i used your suggestion mentioned in OR. That means when a .desktop file executes a BASH script which has chromium-browser 'blablabla' &  then it fails so that `&` symbol is not compatible for .desktop executions